# How to get suggestions from onQueryTextChange()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**How to get suggestions(android.widget.SearchView)  from sqlite cursor and show in the listdropdown:**

```
searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new OnSuggestionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionClick(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

/////////////////////////////////////

```
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                    Log.e("onQueryTextSubmit", arg0);
                    return false;
                }
```

///////////////////////////////

```
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {

                    Log.e("onQueryTextChange", arg0);


                    // Call sqlite cursor to get names 
                    // click on the name to get more data*


                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read our [blog](http://mobikul.com/android-inflating-search-suggestions-from-network/). Here we are trying to get suggestion from the network and you can do the same from your db.

Or you can get the help by this google [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#IntentForSuggestions).